# Counting spatialpoints in gridcells

Tags: r, gis

SO-gurues!
I am trying to count the densities of surviving units in different gridcells.

I have two shapefiles with points from the two survey periods in question (one before and one after the mortality event). What I intend is to see whether  there is a difference in survival rates and link the proportion of survival to any climatic variable obtained from the raster value of the desired grid. In the code snippet below I have created some random raster and shapefiles.

```
packs = c('raster', 'rgdal', 'spatstat', 'sp' ,'dplyr')
sapply(packs, FUN = 'require', character.only = TRUE)
xy <- matrix(rnorm(1024),32,32) #Creating the desired raster
    image(xy)
    rast <- raster(xy)
    extent(rast) <- c(36,37,-3,-2)
    projection(rast) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

    points <- runifpoint(n =4000, c(36,37,-3,-2))     # Creating the points
    x <- points$x
    y <- points$y
    values <- c(rep(1, 900), rep(0, 3100))
    xy <- cbind(x, y)
    points <- cbind(x, y, values)
    points <- data.frame(points)
    shp <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = xy, data = data.frame(values) ) # creating shpfiles
    projection(shp) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
    subs <- filter(points, values == 1)
    suxy <- select(subs, x,y)
    shpsub <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = suxy, data = data.frame(subs$values)) # creating shpfiles
    projection(shpsub) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
```

When I attempt to extract the points I use the following lines of code

```
shp <- spTransform(shp, projection(rast)) # make sure they have same transformation
shpsub <- spTransform(shpsub, projection(rast))
XY <- xyFromCell(rast, cell = 1:ncell(rast))
v <- as.data.frame(rast)                 #Extract values from raster
XY <- data.frame(XY, v)          # Creating a data frame containing coord., cellno and value
XY$cell <- c(1:ncell(rast))
cells <- cellFromXY(rast,shp)             # find which cells the points are in
cells <- rle(cells)                         # returns a value and a length, fast for counting
cellsfound <- cellFromXY(rast,shpsub)
cellsfound <- rle(cellsfound)
Proportion <- data.frame(cell = cells$values, shp = cells$lengths) 
test <- data.frame(cell = rep(NA,NROW(Proportion)), shpsub = rep(NA, NROW(Proportion))) 
test$cell <- c(cellsfound$values, rep(NA, nrow(test) - length(cellsfound$values))) 
test$shpsub  <- c(cellsfound$lengths, rep(NA, NROW(test) - length(cellsfound$lengths)))
Proportion <- full_join(Proportion, test, by = "cell")
test.Proportion <- mutate(Proportion, Proportion = shpsub/shp)    #Calculating Proportion
XY <- left_join(XY, test.Proportion, by = "cell") # Adding Proportion to coord and cell no.
XY.m <- summarise(XY, )
XY <- na.omit(XY) ; XY <- XY[,-4]
```

As I see it. Using rle() returns the same cells multiple times instead of counting the no of points within each individual cell as was my intention. Can anyone please explain me how to do this in a way that retrieves the information on the number of occurrences in the individual cells?

Comment: `grd <- as(rast, 'SpatialPolygons'); table(over(shp, grd))`

Comment: This line of code is great, bu it does however not make me able to retrieve the cell no from the raster layer (rast) and thus makes it impossible to link it with the information contained within rast.

Comment: you should be able to back-track to the cell # from the output. uniform grid. sequential polygon ids.